# Collection of typed Objects

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, actionscript, air, blackberry-playbook

How do you create a collection of objects, where we declare the object typed used in the collection?

**For example in Java you can do:**

`List<Person>` where `Person` is the object type.

**In AS3/Flex**

`ArrayCollection` which takes **any** object type.

Is there any way to create a list/collection of declared objects in AS3/Flex (or is it impossible due to weakly typed language)?

Thanks
Phil

Comment: AS3 is not weakly typed, unless you choose to make it so by disabling strict mode (which I think few do).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a `Vector`object which is an array whose elements are all the same type:

```
var stringVector:Vector.<String> = new Vector.<String>();
```

Comment: I love Vectors, but I think more information needs to be given about them.  The example given here is for a non-fixed length vector which takes a while to 'populate'.  You can make it fixed length which adds performance.  More about the [performance of data structures here](http://gskinner.com/talks/quickTO/#53).  Plus, Vectors cannot be used for Binding, but there is a wrapper you can use for that called [VectorCollection](http://www.digitalprimates.net/author/codeslinger/2010/05/18/vectorcollection/)

Answer (score 0):

It's called [Vector](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Vector.html) in AS3.